# I can't get Fanxcybox 3 options to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: fancybox-3

I'm using the newest version of Fancybox 3 and I'm trying to implement some options like not showing the toolbar or a different transition effect. I have the css in the header and jquery is at the end of the source code. Why do the options not work? I've used Fancybox earlier without a problem.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="{{ paths.theme }}js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({

    toolbar: "false",
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you understand that it is not possible to give a proper answer without seeing live page/demo? You might have JS error somewhere, but we can not know that by looking at some random code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the real output? Then this line -

```
<script src="{{ paths.theme }}js/scripts.js"></script>
```

will break further execution of JS code and ... nothing will work.

Comment: No, that is just twig code in the template, in the source code this is replaced by a theme url. All other scripts I use work well. Fancybox is also working... except for the options I want to apply. Demo is: https://beta.willembosma.nl/blog/test

Comment: Oh, in that case, try replacing `toolbar: "false"` with `toolbar: false`.

Comment: `"false"` is not the same as `false`, because it is actually a string.